# Perl: Getting substring of a number

Tags: perl, substring

When I run the below code I'm expecting to get `3` but instead I get `345`. what's the best way to achieve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $input = "12345";
my $number = substr($input, 2, 3);
print $number;
```

Edit: Thanks all for your answers, I now see my mistake in believing it was first and last index.

Comment: Change the third parameter to `substring()`, which is the length of the extracted substring, from `3` to `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [substr()](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) states that the third parameter is the length of the string you want to fetch.

```
my $input = "12345";

my $num = substr($input, 2, 1);
```

So `$input` is the string, `2` is the offset, and `1` is the number of characters to fetch (or 'Length', per the documentation).

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd arg to [substr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) is the string length:

```
my $number = substr($input, 2, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun can be done like following

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $input = "12345";

my $number_1 = (split '', $input)[2];
my @number_2 = (split '', $input)[2..4];

say $number_1;
say @number_2;
```

output

```
3
345
```